# Acesso Negado ao tentar excluir diretório com PYTHON

Tags: python, windows, permissões

Possuo varias pastas, e dentro dessas, diversas outras pastas, e preciso entrar de uma em uma para excluir outras pastas (Sim, são muitas pastas aninhadas).

O nome das pastas que devo excluir possuem o seu nome no formato ano+mes (Ex.: 201808), preciso limpar as pastas que são de 2 ou mais meses para trás (Ex.: 201705, 201709, 201806).

Ao utilizar o `os.remove(path)`, o programa me retorna um erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\teste.py", line 36, in <module>
    os.remove(caminhoPastaFinal)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acesso negado: 'C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Área de testes\\pasta1\\pasta2\\pasta3\\pasta4\\201712'
```

Já tentei rodar o código no modo administrador pelo CMD, ocorreu o mesmo erro.
Utilizo o Windows 10.

Gostaria de saber porque não tenho permissão para excluir?

Segue o código:

```
import os
from datetime import *

def verificarNome(nomePasta):
    mes=nomePasta[-2:]
    ano=nomePasta[:-2]
    if ano<anoAtual:
        return True
    elif mes<=mesAtual:
        return True
    return False


dataAtual = datetime.now()
anoAtual = str(dataAtual.year)
mesAtual = dataAtual.month
if mesAtual < 10:
    mesAtual = "0"+str(mesAtual-2)
else:
    mesAtual = str(mesAtual-2)

caminhoPai = 'C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Área de testes'

for caminhoPasta in os.listdir(caminhoPai): #Logo farei uma função recursiva que diminua esse código, mas ainda tenho que estudá-las
    caminhoFilho1 = caminhoPai+"\\"+caminhoPasta
    for caminhoPasta2 in os.listdir(caminhoFilho1):
        caminhoFilho2 = caminhoFilho1+"\\"+caminhoPasta2
        for caminhoPasta3 in os.listdir(caminhoFilho2):
            caminhoFilho3 = caminhoFilho2+"\\"+caminhoPasta3
            for caminhoPasta4 in os.listdir(caminhoFilho3):
                caminhoFilho4 = caminhoFilho3+"\\"+caminhoPasta4
                arrayPastasVerificar = os.listdir(caminhoFilho4)
                for pastaFinal in arrayPastasVerificar:
                    if verificarNome(pastaFinal): 
                        caminhoPastaFinal = caminhoFilho4+"\\"+pastaFinal
                        os.remove(caminhoPastaFinal)
```

Comment: Esse erro é comum quando se está manipulando um diretório que está aberto no seu computador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente vamos otimizar esse código:

- ao invés de usar `os.listdir()` use `os.walk()` porque ele já é automaticamente recursivo.
- Além disso podemos tratar o nome da pasta como data direto usando `strptime`.
- Uma outra otimização é usar `shutil.rmtree()` para remover a pasta - essa função já remove automaticamente o conteúdo da pasta primeiro. Isso pode ajudar com o problema de permissão, já que não é permitido remover pastas com `os.remove()` se elas não estiverem vazias.

Fica assim:

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime

este_mes = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)
mes_passado = (este_mes - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1)
dois_meses_atras = (mes_passado - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1)

for caminho, pastas, arquivos in os.walk(caminhoPai):
    for pasta in pastas[:]:
        try:
            data_pasta = datetime.datetime.strptime(pasta, '%Y%m')
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if data_pasta < dois_meses_atras:
            pastas.remove(pasta)
            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(caminho, pasta))
```

Feito isso, podemos atacar o problema de permissão. Além da pasta estar vazia (o que foi resolvido acima usando `rmtree`), pode dar problema de permissão quando tem algum arquivo aberto dentro de uma pasta dessas,  ou então se o usuário que está executando o script não tiver realmente permissão no gerenciador de arquivos do windows.

- Tente fechar todos os arquivos e programas abertos;
- verifique as permissões da pasta clicando com o botão direito nela e indo em propriedades. Veja se o usuário que executou o program tem a permissão para remover a pasta.

Comment: Valeu! O problema era utilizar o .remove() sem apagar os arquivos antes, não sabia que ele apagava apenas pastas vazias, vou testar seu código mais otimizado, e assim que funcionar marco como solução. Muito obrigado!